# How does one "count up" using a recursive function using only one parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, tail-recursion

The aim of the function is very simple. Using **only one int-type argument,** it recursively prints as many lines as the argument dictates. The first line contains one character, the second (assuming the argument is not one) two characters, and so on, until the nth line which contains n characters is printed.

With only one argument and no declaration of variables outside the function, I can't figure out how to properly establish a fluid frame of reference for my base case that is not pseudo-iteration. The "counting down" I can abstractly represent is the lessening of absence, which obviously requires something to replace it with. Because the output only has to be one character, I have considered making an absurdly long string and slicing it the proper amount of times using the parameter, but have since rejected the idea for its lack of creativity.

Is there a solution to this problem that I'm just not seeing?

Comment: Could you share the code to your function?

Comment: Counting down, there is an implicit, externally known base case of 0 that you can test against for termination. No such implicit case exists for counting up.

Comment: The case for iterating from `n` to 0 rather than from 0 to `n` is similar; most instruction sets include a comparison to 0 that you can take advantage of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overthinking it. You want to recurse down to the base case, then print lines on the way back out:

```
def count(num):
    if num > 1:
        count(num-1)
    print("|"*num)
```

Sample output:

```
>>> def count(num):
...     if num > 1:
...         count(num-1)
...     print("|"*num)
... 
>>> count(4)
|
||
|||
||||
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thanks so much! In my previous classes/projects, I somehow got away with thinking of recursion in the static framework of base case > step execution > recursive call. Your comment helped me see the process in a new light, and I've since improved my efficacy with recursion and rewritten some old code to use the process more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

You can get locked into thinking that you must first print, and then make the recursive call. But in this case you need to first make the recursive call and then print, which changes the order.